# Emoji and accent encoding in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the next String from my api

```
"Ã Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã¼ Ã± \uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE06\uD83D\uDE05"
```

from a response in a json format

```
{
    'apiText': "Ã Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã¼ Ã± \uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE06\uD83D\uDE05",
    'otherInfo': 'etc.',
    .
    .
    .
}
```

it contains accents `Ã Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã¼ Ã±` that are not correctly encoded and it contains emojis `\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE06\uD83D\uDE05`

so far i have tried

```
var json = jsonDecode(response.body)
String apiText = json['apiText'];
List<int> bytes = apiText.codeUnits;
comentario = utf8.decode(bytes);
```

but produces a

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 21)`

how can i get the correct text with accents and emoji?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://pub.dev/packages/characters ?

Comment: Also, what type is `apiText` in your code? It does not really make sense to toString() and then try parse the codeUnits as UTF-8 since codeUnits from a `String` are UTF-16 in Dart.

Comment: @julemand101 is String type, i edited the question to show the type

Comment: Ok, so `apiText` contains literally the text you have posted with backslashes?

Comment: @julemand101 yes, i get this text from the api ""Ã Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã¼ Ã± \uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04\uD83D\uDE01\uD83D\uDE06\uD83D\uDE05"
" but the "Ã Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã¼ Ã± " is actually characters with accents "Á é í ó ú ñ", so i encode them to get the actual text, but in the process the emoji ("\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D ... ") kills the encode. The api can send any text with latin like characters and emojis interspersed (it is a commentary system, that's what i'm getting, the users comments)

Comment: It seems more likely that you are parsing with the wrong charset in your `getTextFromApi` method. Does the API not specify what charset it returns? Can you e.g. show the code which handles the response from calling the API?

Comment: @julemand101 i edited the question to show specifically how i get the response from the api

Comment: Ok, but what charset was specified in the HTTP header? Did you specify to the API that you wanted the response in UTF-8?

Comment: @julemand101 yes , send this headers
```Map<String, String> header = {
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      };```

Comment: I am guessing you are using the `http` package to handle the request. Can you try: `jsonDecode(utf8.decode(resonse.bodyBytes))`

Comment: @julemand101 you are a wizard dude, that resolved the problem, than you very much

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer but the quick answer is you should take a look at the documentation for `body`: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/body.html . The problem is that if the HTTP response does not contain any charset it will assume it is LATIN1.

Comment: @julemand101 oh that's correct. Write the answer i will validate it as the correct one

Comment: Added an answer. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on the fact you called `response.body` I assumes you are using the `http` package which does have the `body` property on `Response` objects.

You should note the following detail in the documentation:

> This is converted from bodyBytes using the `charset` parameter of the `Content-Type` header field, if available. If it's unavailable or if the encoding name is unknown, latin1 is used by default, as per RFC 2616.

Well, it seems rather likely that it cannot figure out the charset and therefore defaults to latin1 which explains how your response got messed up.

A solution for this is to use the [`resonse.bodyBytes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html) instead which contains the raw bytes from the response. You can then manually parse this with e.g. `utf8.decode(resonse.bodyBytes)` if you are sure the response should be parsed as UTF-8.

Comment: Finally got to look at this life-saver after being loggerheads for about hours! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your function as

```
String utf8convert(String text) {
  var bytes = text.codeUnits;

  String decodedCode = utf8.decode(bytes, allowMalformed: true);
  if (decodedCode.contains("�")) {
    return text;
  }
  return decodedCode;
}
```