# How to show emoji in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an api from which I am fetching messages. These messages might contain emoji.
When it does contain emoji Text Widget is not displaying it correctly.
I just want to display them on the screen. Help if possible.

Thank you :)

```
class Message{
String text;

  Message(){
   this.text = get_data_from_api()['text'];
  }
}

message = Message();
return Container(
  child: Text(message.text), 
);
```

No [Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter?noredirect=1&lq=1)
won't do it. I can do that but it only works if you have emoji in a string, that is explicitly plasing an emoji in string works fine for me. but when I am using something similar to the code above. I am getting, this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6FDu.png)

digging more into it I found that if I print my response on console it is

"ð­ð­ð­ð­"

and if I print a emoji it is

So

I am using

```
Response.fromStream(await request.send())
```

from http/http.dart

So is that the problem ?

Comment: Look at this answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839834/10210902

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

I did figured it out

I was taking data from an API. So while decoding for some reason it was not decoding utf-8 so what I needed to do was add

```
utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
```

in place of `response.body` and it was solved

Reference: [Emoji and accent encoding in dart/flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381058/emoji-and-accent-encoding-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an emoji image explicitly present in the response from your API and you want to display it in your text, your should try adding WidgetSpan inside your RichText below is an example of how to do it :

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "Click ",
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 14),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: " to add",
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

In the above example they have used the material icon( Icon(Icons.add)). If you want to replace that from the image your get from the API, you can use ImageIcon instead of Icon widget. Follow this link to know how to use ImageIcon : https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-imageicon-widget-examples

Reference : [Add image to RichText element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287059/add-image-to-richtext-element)

Comment: As it receives messages they don't have same emoji nor is there a way to know which one is used in a perticular message.

Comment: In what form are you receiving the emoji from your API ? Are the text and emoji seperated or combined ?

Comment: Sarvesh Thank you, It was not decoding using utf-8. so I had to do that manually, reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381058/emoji-and-accent-encoding-in-dart-flutter. Thank you for your response :)